# Is the associated grouplike $\gamma=uS(u)^{-1}$ of a quasi-triangular Hopf algebra always the square of another grouplike?

Tags: gr.group-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $(H,R)$ be a finite-dimensional quasi-triangular Hopf algebra, lets say generated by group-like and skew-primitive elements (I actually need it for $H$ fin. dim. pointed with $G(H)$ abelian). Let $u\in H$ be the Drinfeld't element and $\gamma=uS(u)^{-1} \in G(H)$ the associated group-like element. Does there always exist another grouplike $g \in G(H)$, s.t. $g^2=\gamma$?

EDIT: I just saw that if $(H,R)$ admits a ribbon element $\nu$, then $g:=\nu^{-1}u$ is group-like and $S(\nu)=\nu$ implies $g^2=uS(u)^{-1}=\gamma$.

Comment: Any reason that $G(H)$ can't be an elementary abelian 2-group?

Comment: It can be, but why should this contradict the statement

Comment: It immediately contradicts it if $\gamma$ is non-trivial.  I just can't recall if there's anything that forces $\gamma=1$ when $H$ is fin. dim. pointed with $G(H)$ an elementary abelian 2-group.

Comment: I don't know either but that's definetely a good starting point